# Which of these query styles is more efficient to use? the links within FROM clause, or the links in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, db2

Which style of query is more efficient to use?
This one?

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    Customer A
    JOIN Order B
    ON A.cusid = B.cusid
WHERE A.cusid = '12345'
```

Or This one?

```
SELECT *
FROM
   Customer,
   Order
WHERE
   Customer.cusid = Order.cusid
   AND
   Customer.cusid = '12345'
```

In school we are thought of the first style i wrote above but I am using the latter style, i'm just curious which one is efficient.

Comment: Generally, you want to [avoid using the old `JOIN` syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) (the second one).

Answer (score 0):

As your question seems to be targeted at DB2, it is good to know that DB2 does care how you write the query. Both query styles are transformed to the same internal query representation. That internal representation is used to optimize the query by applying rewrite rules based on common rules and statistics about your data, the system, and available resources.